# Passing pointer to constructor of class

Tags: c++, object, pointers

I'm not quite sure what the difference between passing `*d` and `d2` to the constructor is:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Data
{

public:
    int number;
};

class Node {

public:

    Data data;  

    Node() {};

    Node(Data d) : data(d) {};

};

int main()
{
    
    Data* d = new Data();
    Node* n = new Node(*d);
    
    Data d2;
    Node* n2 = new Node(d2);


    return 0;
}
```

I can pass *d and d2, but in both scenarios, the data member "data" in the class "Node" is still an object by itself, is that correct? Or is there even a difference between passing an object and a dynamic object?

Comment: There are three `Data` objects here: `data` member in the class, `d` constructor parameter, and either `d` or `d2`. The former two don't care about the third.

Comment: Right.  Since this is C++ and not C#, all of those 4 objects are separate objects, and when you assign one to the other you are copying the data from one object to another.  (You can print out the address of any object with `printf` if you want to check this.)

Comment: @David Grayson thanks, that answers my question :)

Comment: Actually, let's see, there are 4 long-lived data objects, and from the perspective of the `main` function they are named: `*d`, `d2`, `n->data`, and `n2->data`.  There are also 2 *temporary* data objects that are created when you call the Node constructor `Node(Data d)`, since calling that involves creating a `Data` object on the stack named `d` and you call the constructor twice.  So there are 6 Data objects in sight and several copy (or move) operations are performed to pass data between them.

Answer (score 1):

From `Node`'s perspective, the constructor receives a `Data` object. It doesn't care if this object is dynamically allocated using `new` or not.

Answer (score 0):

from node perspective, the constructor of node need an object of type data ,so it only care about data object type, it don't care about its place in memory (static memory   or dynamic memory) *d and d2 represent data objects so your code is correct.